# Embedding Wave Dashboards into a Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, einstein-analytics

I'm trying to embed a Wave dashboard onto a Visualforce page, but I'm getting the error "
This dashboard doesn't exist, has been deleted, or you may not have access to it".

I checked the sharing settings on the dashboard, and the entire organization has manager access. The entire app (where this dashboard is hosted), is also shared with the Entire Organization with manager access.

The code I'm using is:

```
<apex:page sidebar="true" standardController="Opportunity">

  wave:dashboard dashboardId="0FKB000000006Y7OAI" 
        showTitle="true" 
        height="800px" 
        openLinksInNewWindow="true" 
        filter="{'datasets' : {'opportunity': [ {'fields':['Id'], 'selection': ['{!Opportunity.Id}']}]}}"/>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is a Wave(Einstein) analytics access issue, not with the VF page.**

As a **System Administrator**, view this VF page and navigate to the associated Dashboard this page is using **(Click open in wave icon)**.

- Click Share (round arrow icon pointing to right side)
- You will see the pop-up options - Give Access,Post to feed, Download
- At the bottom of this pop up, you will see a message.
  -To invite others to view, edit, or manage this Dashboard, click
  "XXX" and share the app. XXX is the App in which this dashboard belongs.
- Click on **XXX (App)**, and all you need to do is **give access** to the affected user. (Viewer/Editor/Manager) - generally we might want to give **Viewer**.

This should resolve. Actually the dashboard is inside an App, and the App is not shared with the affected user, hence wasn't able to view it in the VF page.